# install torchaudio on AWS training container

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, torchaudio

What is the proper way to install torchaudio in AWS sagemaker GPU container? and why is it not pre-installed?

I tried `pip install torchaudio` but it tries to uninstall and install pytorch as well that breaks the whole container. I got `segmentation fault` error probably because it installed CPU based version of pytorch and torchaudio.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that pip auto uninstall and installs Pytorch probably shows that you're installing a [torchaudio version which is uncompatible with the pytorch version.](https://github.com/speechbrain/speechbrain/issues/1092)
Perhaps:

1. Find a matching set of PyTorch and TorchAudio. Test that they install well locally.
2. Make sure you find an [AWS DLC container with such PyTorch version](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/tree/master/pytorch).
3. pip install torchaudio specifying the exact version you need. Test this with Docker on your local machine, cloud not needed.